# Creation and copy directories

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that takes a directory, copies all its files to a new directory that I create. So the script has two arguments. The first being an existing directory, and the second being the created directory.

Here is what I have so far:

```
dir1=$1
dir2=$2

mkdir $2
cp $1/. $2
```

Yet my new directory is always empty. Is it a syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp -r $1/. $2
```

Do you need to add recursion.

Comment: No, what exactly is the flag -r?

Comment: You are telling it to copy recursively.  Take the contents of dir1 and copy them to dir2

Answer (score 1):

If you tell it to copy `.`, you're actually telling it to copy the directory (`.` links to the directory it's in, so `cd ././././././././` loops on the same directory).

You can either do:

```
cp $1/* $2
```

to copy all files from "$1" to "$2", but not subdirectories

```
cp $1/. -r $2
```

to copy all files and subdirectories recursively, and also treating special files like regular files (ie. if it finds a pipe, it reads from the pipe and writes to a regular file).

```
cp $1/. -R $2
```

to copy all files and subdirectories recursively, and also preserving special files

```
cp $1/. -a $2
```

to copy everything, and also preserve links, group permissions, and special files.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

`cp $1/. $2` I think you need use wildcard instead dot 
`cp $1/* $2`

Another way is to use recursive copy

```
cp -r $1/* $2 # copy the whole directory into the second one recursively (e.i. including subdirectories)
cp -ar $1/* $2 # this will keep the sym links intact (not trying to replace them with the file they point)
```